# Flash Builder, loading assets for mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, flash, flash-builder

I am using flash builder to make an app for android/ios.

How would you recommend I use assets such as images and sounds. Should I embed them or use loader?

Any benefits to each one.

I have a fair amount of assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert on flash, but I ended up embedding the resources. The ease of compile-time resource checking. You just need to be sure to load each images/sounds when you have enough time to do so between frames.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile apps embed is just easier.  You don't need to worry about accessing the file system and purchasing/downloading is easier since you are not bundeling anything with it.  The initial download will be about the same size unless you were planning on loading the assets to the device at runtime from the web.  I would caution against that unless it was absolutely necessary.  My experience is user are accustomed to a large download, but but load time of the app each time it opens should be minimal.

I also like that FlashBuilder will check your embed code and make sure the file is present and spelled correctly - one less thing to worry about